# TestMain multiple definitions found

Tags: testing, go

If I define, two tests, each with its own `TestMain` method, `go test` errors: `"multiple definitions found of TestMain"`.

I can understand and was expecting this behaviour actually, because, there should not be more than one TestMain in the same package. However, I don't know what to do now. Each test suite has its own needs. I need to create distinct `TestMain`s to setup the tests, *of course, without renaming my packages*.

I could do that easily in other languages with setup methods like `before`, `after`, which is **unique to a test class**.

I'll probably go and use [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify)'s suites. Sad that this is not supported in stdlib.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: [subtests](https://blog.golang.org/subtests) are basically simple "suites". If you want more flexibility, that's were external packages can help out, or you write your own simple wrappers.

Comment: @JimB It turns out that, subtests are very cool, I don't know why I couldn't found them before, duckduckgoing all around. Thx for that!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [M.Run](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#M.Run).

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setup()
    code := m.Run() 
    close()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

See [subtest](https://blog.golang.org/subtests) for additional info.

More detailed example:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func setup()    {}
func teardown() {}

func setup2()    {}
func teardown2() {}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    var wrappers = []struct {
        Setup    func()
        Teardown func()
    }{
        {
            Setup:    setup,
            Teardown: teardown,
        },
        {
            Setup:    setup2,
            Teardown: teardown2,
        },
    }

    for _, w := range wrappers {
        w.Setup()
        code := m.Run()
        w.Teardown()

        if code != 0 {
            panic("code insn't null")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he was referring to [`TestMain(m *testing.M)`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main), but yes, subtests are the easiest method without an external test framework.

Comment: @JimB indeed, I was thinking about [M.Run](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#M.Run) but wrote about T.Run.

Comment: How this solves my problem? Can you give an example? I made some research on subtests; with them, I need to wrap my tests under another test, so I can use before/each hooks in the test. But, how is that related to `TestMain`?

Comment: @inanc you need to do the same stuff with before/after wrappers(setup and close respectively in my answer) and then run main with `m.Run()`

Comment: @olegkovalov I still didn't get it, sorry, can you update the example? How am I going to use `TestMain` for distinct test files which need distinct setup/tear conditions in the same package?

Comment: @inanc see updated answer, hope this will help you :)

Comment: @olegkovalov Hmm, how is this different than writing all the `setup1`, `setup2`, `teardown1`, `teardown2` funcs into `TestMain` directly. Isn't this going to run `setup1` and `teardown1` if I only run my 2nd test file's tests only? Thx! :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146702/discussion-between-olegkovalov-and-inanc).

Comment: Using subtests like you suggest, is there a way to prefix the tests so that you can identify which is throwing the error ?

Comment: @BlueMagma There is no such ability for `M.Run` but we've that for `T.Run` https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Run

Comment: See paragraph `Introducing sub tests` here https://dave.cheney.net/2019/05/07/prefer-table-driven-tests

Comment: This example doesn't work with the `-run` argument. Or at least it becomes dependent upon the order the setups run in. If I filter the test running using `-run` to something which requires `setup2` then my test will be run immediately following `setup` and then fail because the proper setup hasn't run yet.